# LOCATE vs INSTR

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT INSTR('1234','2')  #returns 2
    SELECT LOCATE('2','1234') #returns 2
```

Besides the argument numbering are there any significant differences to be aware of before choosing either of the functions?

Comment: The manual says that `INSTR` is equal to the call to `LOCATE` when 2 arguments are supplied. Quote: `This is the same as the two-argument form of LOCATE(), except that the order of the arguments is reversed.`. Unless you use `LOCATE` with 3 arguments, then what you wrote above is identical. If you need the position of the string in a substring, then obvious choice (to me, personally) would be `INSTR` since it's clear what you're after.

Comment: Thanks Mjh that was helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Locate**

The `LOCATE()` function returns the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

**Instr**

The `INSTR()` function returns the position of the first occurrence of a string in another string.

For example

```
SELECT LOCATE("H", "PHP") AS MatchPosition;`
-- -> returns 2
SELECT INSTR("PHP", "H") AS MatchPosition;
-- -> returns 2
```

And the performance is

```
-- 5.074 sec
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000,INSTR('foobar','foo'));

-- 5.086 sec
SELECT BENCHMARK(100000000,LOCATE('foo','foobar'));
```

Answer (score 11):

The `INSTR()` function starts the search from the ***first character***.

The `LOCATE()` function has ***a third parameter*** which allows you to change the starting position.

```
-- returns 4
SELECT INSTR("Alibaba", "ba")

-- returns 4 because the third parameter was not specified
SELECT LOCATE("ba", "Alibaba")

-- returns 6
SELECT LOCATE("ba", "Alibaba", 5)
```

Comment: Why the following returns 1 ?
```SELECT INSTR("Alibaba", "")
SELECT LOCATE("", "Alibaba")```

Comment: @ManjunathReddy I'm guessing because `"Alibaba"` has an empty string at position 1. In fact, it has a lot of empty strings at position one.